# JqueryUI Datepicker year picker not updating textbox text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am wondering if anyone knows a way to change the JQueryUI Datepicker to update the date text as soon as the year dropdown is changed.

The basics of what I am using is shown in http://jsfiddle.net/H94cc/238/

```
<input type="text" name="DOB" id="DOB" class="cat_textbox datepicker" value="10/10/1976" />


 // UI Date Picker
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ 
yearRange: '-80:-04' ,
changeYear: true,
changeMonth: true
});

$(".datepicker").datepicker({

    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "/images/calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

If you click on the text, then choose a year, and click somewhere else without choosing the day again it closes without updating the text.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use onChangeMonthYear event as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - On change month,year</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script>
      $(function() {
        var changingDate = false;
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            yearRange: '-80:-04' ,
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            onChangeMonthYear: function(y, m, i) {
                var d = i.selectedDay;
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(y, m - 1, d));
            }
        });
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" name="DOB" id="DOB" class="cat_textbox datepicker" value="10/10/1976" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion.  There is a small issue on chrome with the function in that it makes you double click on the year dropdown.

Comment: Actually sorry, that seems to be with the consistently there with fiddle, so it's not to do with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the setDate event in datepicker, when your change event happens.

```
$target_node.change(function() {
   $your_date_node.datepicker({your_config})
                  .datepicker('setDate', your_date);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, from some reason "i" variable was not populating; also it was "datepick()" and not "datepicker()" - not sure what plugin was used.

This is what I got working in the end:

```
    var datepicker = $('.datepicker').datepick({
       changeYear: true,
       changeMonth: true,
       onChangeMonthYear: function (y, m, i) {
          var date = $(this).datepick('getDate');
          var d = date[0].getDate();
          $(this).datepick('setDate', new Date(y, m - 1, d));
       }
});
```